# Find sum of series $\frac{1}{6} + \frac{5}{6 \cdot 12} + \frac{5\cdot 8}{6 \cdot 12 \cdot 18} + \dotsb$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Find the sum of the  following infinite series:
>   $$ \frac{1}{6} + \frac{5}{6 \cdot 12} + \frac{5\cdot 8}{6 \cdot 12 \cdot 18} + \frac{5\cdot 8 \cdot 11}{6 \cdot 12 \cdot 18 \cdot 24} + \dotsb$$

I was trying this question many times but I could not get it. I was trying to solve this problem by D'Alembert ratio test, but I did not get my answer. My teacher gave me this question as a homework, I don't any hint or idea to solved this question, I was trying many times but didn't get it.

If anybody help me I would be very thankful. Thank you.

Comment: D'Alembert is used to find the radius of convergence, and tells nothing about the *value* of a convergent series.

Comment: Looks like a case of the binomial theorem.

Comment: It seems that it's like $-\sqrt[3]{1-x}$

Comment: The first term of $\frac16$ does not really fit the others

Comment: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\prod_{k=1}^n\dfrac{1}{2^{k+1}}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{3^k}\right)$$

Comment: The generating function is $g(z)=\dfrac{(2-z)^{2/3}-2^{2/3}}{2 (2-z)^{2/3} z}$ and the sum is $g(1)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}$

Comment: my teacher said that answer  1/2(4^1/3 -1) i don't know how it come @ raffaele